# How do I set up Moq so that I can simulate SignalR calls to client side (browser)?

Tags: signalr, moq, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I'm building out a UnitTest frame work for our SignalR 2.x application.
I'm using Moq to mock the required framework.
I see how I can use Moq to interact with calls on the hub/server side.
I'm a little confused as to how I would do this on the client side.
How do I set up Moq so that I can simulate SignalR calls to client side (browser)?

I've seen 2 methods for mocking the client:
**1:**

```
var mockClients = new Mock<IHubCallerConnectionContext>();
Clients = mockClients.Object;
```

**2:**

```
const string connectionId = "1234";
const string hubName = "SomeHub";
StateChangeTracker tracker = new StateChangeTracker();
var mockPipelineInvoker = new Mock<IHubPipelineInvoker>(); 

var mockConnection = new Mock<IConnection>();
Clients = new HubConnectionContext(mockPipelineInvoker.Object, mockConnection.Object, hubName, connectionId, tracker);
```

**So, consider the following call from the hub to the client:**

```
ActiveClients.Group(groupName).onNotifyClient(hubMessage);
```

I'm new to using Moq and still figuring it out on the fly.
Info/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
JohnB

Answer (score 0):

There is tutorial by the SignalR team on this , see [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/troubleshooting-and-debugging/unit-testing-signalr-applications)

Comment: I've already looked at the sample. It's a good starting point for when you are blasting messages to all connected clients. It does not address my needs. I'm trying to figure out how to mock the group object so I can unit test distributing messages to various groups.